# VF page reload looping

Tags: apex, visualforce

I created a formula field on the customer Account Summary object to calculate the RecordTypeName__c rather than use the controller to figure that out.

The controller loads OK but when I add the jscript to the VisualForce page the page starts looping reloading itself and the VF page shows this error:

> Attempt to de-reference a null object

```
<script type='text/javascript' 
  window.onload= function Redirect() {
      redirection();
  }
</script 
<apex:actionFunction name="redirection" action="{!redirectAcctNewPage}" />
```

Apex Controller:

```
    //Constructors
public AccountSummaryController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    try {
        this.stdController = controller;
        this.AccountSummary = (Account_Summary__c) controller.getRecord();
        this.ParentAcct = new Account();
        this.IsNew = (this.AccountSummary.Id == null);
        this.hidecols = true; //toggles hidden columns. true=show all hidden columns.
        risk1 = 'null';

        if (this.AccountSummary.Report_Status__c == 'Final') {
            this.statusupdate = true; //toggles report status. true=report status is final.
        } else {
            this.statusupdate = false;
        }

        if (!this.IsNew) {
            //Lock record processing
            this.isLocked = Approval.isLocked(this.AccountSummary.Id);  //test is record is locked via approval request.   //causing error Arg 1 cannot be null.
            if (this.isLocked) {
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Warning, 'CRE locked. Report Status set to Final. To edit click button "Mark CRE as Draft."'));
            }
        }

        //Get Url Parameters
        if (this.IsNew) {
            Map<string, string> params = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();
            //this.RecordTypeId = params.get(URL_PARAM_RECORD_TYPE_ID);   //only needed for new record
            this.AccountId = params.get(URL_PARAM_ACCOUNT_ID);          //only needed for new record
            this.ExternalId = params.get(URL_PARAM_EXTERNAL_ID);        //only needed for new record
            this.SubmissionYear = params.get(URL_PARAM_SUBMISSION_YEAR);
            this.Name = params.get(URL_PARAM_SUBMISSION_NAME);
            //this.ExternalId = ParentAcct.External_ID_BA__c;
        }

        //Get Submission Year   //used to query for financial submission and contract records.
        this.SubmissionYear = this.AccountSummary.Name;


        if (SubmissionYear == null) {
            SubmissionYear = this.SubmissionYear;  //grabs value passed in thru URL as new record.
        }
        if (SubmissionYear == null) {  // need a year if the url year is null as well.
            SubmissionYear = string.valueof(system.today().year());
        }
        if (SubmissionYear != null) {
            this.accountsummary.name = this.SubmissionYear;
            this.ContractYear = string.valueof((integer.valueof(SubmissionYear) - 1));
        } else {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'Invalid Submission Year. Please contact the help desk with this error'));
        }


        //Get Account Id Prefix
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult dsr = Account.sObjectType.getDescribe();  // errored when
        this.accountIdPrefix = dsr.getKeyPrefix();

        //Get Account Id
        Id AccountId = this.AccountSummary.Account_Name__c;

        //Get RecordType  //used to redirect to correct pagetype when loaded.   
        //this.RecordTypeId =  ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType');
        //this.RecordTypeName = this.AccountSummary.RecordTypeName__c;

        if (AccountId == null) {
            //string param1 = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccId');
            string param1 = this.AccountId;  //grabs value passed in thru URL as new record.

            if (isAccountId(param1)) {
                AccountId = param1;
            } else {
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'Invalid Account Id. Please contact the help desk with this error'));
            }
        }

        //Get External Account Business Affiliate Id   //used to query acct for submission records.
        ExternalId = this.AccountSummary.AccountExt_ID_BA__c;

        if (ExternalId == null) {
            ExternalId = this.ExternalId;  //grabs value passed in thru URL as new record.
            ExternalId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('exid');
        }


        //Load Account Record
        List<Account> accounts = queryAccounts(AccountId);

        if (accounts.isEmpty() == true) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'No records were found. Please contact the help desk with this error'));
        } else if (accounts.size() > 1) {

            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'More than 1 record found. Please contact the help desk with this error'));

        }

        else {
            this.ParentAcct = accounts[0];
            this.AccountSummary.Account_Name__c = this.ParentAcct.Id;
        }

        SelectedSubmissions = new List<String>();

        if (!this.IsNew) {
            //Get stored selection options when re-opening saved record.
            this.SubmissionOptions = getSubmissionOptions(this.ExternalId, this.SubmissionYear);    //this is adding 2 bogus submission options
            this.SelectedSubmissions = toArray(this.AccountSummary.SelectedOptions__c);
            getSelectedSubmissions();   //used to fetch all submission options
        }

        else {
            this.SubmissionOptions = getSubmissionOptions(this.ExternalId, this.SubmissionYear);    //this is adding 2 bogus submission options
        }


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
    }

}


//Public Methods


//Open and view page according to record type. There are multiple CRE versions with seperate record types. 
public PageReference redirectAcctNewPage() {
    PageReference pageRef = null;    
    //Get RecordType  //used to redirect to correct pagetype when loaded.   
    this.RecordTypeName = this.AccountSummary.RecordTypeName__c;

    try {
        if(this.RecordTypeName.equals('New_Account_Summary'))
        {   
            pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/PROD_UW_AccountSummary');
            pageRef.getParameters().put('id', this.AccountSummary.Id);
            pageRef.setRedirect(true);  
        }
        else 
        {
            pageRef = new PageReference('/' + this.AccountSummary.Id);
            pageRef.getParameters().put('inline', '0');
            pageRef.setRedirect(true);   
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
    }
     return pageRef;
}
```

Comment: I think, `this` reference refers to controller instance and not of `AccountSummary` because your action is instance method.  Post your whole controller code to get better understanding,

Comment: I added the constructor above.